# Mockito throws NotAMockException using spring mvc injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito

Hy guys,

I am trying to make a test using mockito on a web application that uses spring mvc.
When it executes this line **"Mockito.reset(notificacaoRepositoryMock);"** it throws **"org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40"**

I saw that in am example and it worked, I can't find what I am doing wrong here.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebAppConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class NotificacaoControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private NotificacaoRepository notificacaoRepositoryMock;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // *** Error here ***
        Mockito.reset(notificacaoRepositoryMock);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
```

My TestContext is:

```
@Configuration
public class TestContext {

       @Bean
        public MessageSource messageSource() {
            ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

            messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
            messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);

            return messageSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public NotificacaoRepository notificacaoRepository() {
            return Mockito.mock(NotificacaoRepository.class);
        }
}
```

The class I want mock is a CrudRepository interface

```
public interface NotificacaoRepository extends CrudRepository<Notificacao, Long> {
}
```

and, I think, the relevant part of my pom.xml is (spring versions and mockito)

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.21</mysql.connector.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.data.version>1.8.0.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
</properties>
...
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

UPDATE

@jfcorugedo i tryed exactly what you said but I keep receiving the same error. My test context is just

```
@Configuration
public class TestContext {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public NotificacaoRepository notificacaoRepository() {
            return Mockito.mock(NotificacaoRepository.class);
        }
}
```

and my test class now is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@Import({TestContext.class})
public class NotificacaoControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    NotificacaoRepository notificacaoRepositoryMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Mockito.reset(notificacaoRepositoryMock); // Error >> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of creating a bean, did you try to put just `@Mock NotificacaoRepository repo;` to beginning of your test class?

Comment: @mtyurt: This would not work because he uses the `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` test runner, and not the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` runner.

Comment: In later version of mockito there's a `MockitoRule` that allows that

Answer (score 2):

This is because Spring create a proxy around your bean.

Try to not inject mock using Spring

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebAppConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class NotificacaoControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private NotificacaoRepository notificacaoRepositoryMock;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        notificacaoRepositoryMock = Mockito.mock(NotificacaoRepository.class);
        Mockito.reset(notificacaoRepositoryMock);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
```

Comment: This solution only creates a mock inside the test class, but it doesn't replace the instance that Spring is actually using

Comment: Yes, to manage dependencies injection, one could look : http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/01/mock-autowired-fields/

Comment: I suggest looking at Springockito.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are trying to **replace** the spring bean with a mock version.

In that case you have to annotate the method that produces your mock with the annotation `@Primary`, so Spring could choose the mock object by default in each autowired field (of course if it doesn't have any qualifier).

If you're trying to use a Spring context in your test that has some *real* beans and other *mock* beans, you have to follow this steps:

- Create a `@Configuration` class in your test folder that inject a mock instance of the beans you want to mock
- Import this configuration class in your test

For instance:

**Configuration class that injects the mock**

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import xxx.xxx.xxx.NotificacaoRepository;

@Configuration
public class MockConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public NotificacaoRepository registerMock() {
        return mock(NotificacaoRepository.class);
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@Import({MockConfigurer.class})
public class NotificacaoControllerTest {

    //Now the instance injected here should be a mock object
    @Autowired
    private NotificacaoRepository notificacaoRepositoryMock;

    ...
}
```

Comment: The solution of Vyncent worked, anyways, I tryed to use `@Primary` in my bean method in TestContext.class but I keep getting same error. I didn't change anything I just added `@Primary` annotation

Comment: No, I don't think so. With the solution of Vyncent you're only creating a mock of `NotificacaoRepository`, but where are you using it? Spring has its **own instance** of this bean, so the only thing you're doing is creating a mock inside your test

Comment: @Vyncent this link shows how to mock the autowired fields but in that case the test has the object that is being tested. It tests OrderService and he creates an OrderService object to call the tested method. In my case I don't have the object, I test using a POST with MockMvc `mockMvc.perform(post("/notificacao")`